# Using typedef in implementation of class template

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

I've spent the last hour trying to solve a templated `typdef` issue by searching Google and SO, but unfortunately haven't been able to find something that fits what I'm trying to do closely enough (I'm sure someone will be better at searching than I am though, and shout me in the right direction, so apologies in advance).

I'm following Koenig and Moo's Accelerated C++, where in chapter 11 they go over the implementation of a simplified `vector` class template.

I'm keeping the implementation separate from the class and function declarations, by having a `vector_impl.h` file and a `vector.h` file respectively, where `vector_impl.h` is included at the bottom of `vector.h`. However, doing so has caused compilation issues with `typedef`s defined in `vector.h` that are used in `vector_impl.h`.

I have the following in `vector.h`:

```
template<typename T>
class Vector{
public:
    typedef T* iterator;
    ...
    iterator data_;
    iterator available_;
    iterator limit_;
    ...
}

#include "vector_impl.h"
```

And use `iterator` in `vector_impl.h` as return types,

```
template<typename T>
iterator Vector<T>::begin() {
    return data_;
}
```

as input arguments, and as variables passed to `std` functions as follows,

```
template<typename T>
void Vector<T>::create(iterator begin, iterator end){
    data_ = allocator_.allocate(end - begin);
    available_ = std::uninitialized_copy(begin, end, data_);
    limit_ = std::uninitialized_copy(begin, end, data_);
}
```

So far I've tried a few different suggestions such as defining the `typedef` in `vector.h` with

```
typedef typename T* iterator
```

and then defining the `begin()` function in `vector_impl.h` as

```
template<typename T>
typename Vector<T>::iterator Vector<T>::begin(){
    return data_;
}
```

and have also tried defining `iterator` at the top of `vector_impl.h` as

```
template<typename T>
typedef typename T* iterator;
```

and also

```
template<typename T>
using iterator = T*;
```

but nothing has seemed to work. If anyone could educate me as to how one could use a templated `typedef` outside the class that it was defined in that would be much appreciated.

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe.  `iterator` exists inside `Vector` so you need `template<typename T> typename Vector<T>::iterator Vector<T>::begin() ...`

Comment: @NathanOliver, as mentioned in my post, I've tried `template<typename T> typename Vector<T>::iterator Vector<T>::begin()` to no avail.

Comment: @indigoblue [Works here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11007193df3aa427).  If it is not for you, please edit your question with a [mre].

Comment: @NathanOliver, apologies, you're correct! I hadn't changed the input arguments and all uses of `iterator` inside functions to use `Vector<T>::iterator`. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: No problem.  Glad to help.